# SQL localdb problems with ADO

Tags: sql, ado.net, ado, sql-server-express, localdb

I have a native c++ application which uses ado connections to access a SQL Server Express database. For the demo purpose am planning to use `LocalDB`. But I read that `localdb` doesn't support ado connections. Is this true??

Answer (score 1):

LocalDB supports both ODBC and OLEDB, as long as a recent SQL Server Native client is installed. Where did you read this? Only JDBC etc is not supported (since remote connections are not supported, I guess)

Comment: ok .. let me try .. http://www.sqlcoffee.com/SQLServer2012_0004.htm .. sharing the link

Comment: See this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403614/unable-to-connect-to-sql-localdb